# Como descobrir o diretório do arquivo pelo "inspecionar elemento"

Tags: php, wordpress

Gostaria de saber em qual arquivo ( ou diretório ) se encontra o arquivo do elemento específico de uma página web inspecionado.

Importante: seria um arquivo do wordpress php, e não css.

Answer (score 0):

Na guia 'Source' do Inspecionar você consegue visualizar algumas informações sobre o diretório do arquivo em sites comuns.

PS: só respondi aqui porque não consegui comentar sua pergunta.

Comment: Legal. Mas ele mostra um index dentro do wordpress que no "sources" aparece o código. Porém no servidor está em branco.

Comment: Claro, porque o arquivo .php roda do lado do servidor, para você (no navegador, ou seja, no cliente) ele mostra apenas os retornos, e não necessariamente o código PHP, por isso seria quase impossivel...

Comment: Sim. Mas mesmo baixando o arquivo e abrindo ele também não mostra nada. Apenas a mensagem abaixo:

<?php
// Silence is golden.

Comment: Cara, poderia por o link do que vc está tentando baixar, só para eu dar uma olhada?

Comment: Por gentileza,  é o seguinte.. eu preciso saber em qual arquivo ( ou diretório ) está o código do slider da home desse site.. https://f***.com.br/

Comment: a probabilidade de vc descobrir isso é 5%... Provavelmente, em alguma pasta de plugins do proprio wordpress, mas é dificil dizer só com isso...

Comment: Poise já procurei mas também não achei. Mas beleza.. Obrigado por tentar ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

Se Clicar em cima da imagem e clicar para abrir em uma nova aba, na maioria das vezes dar certo também. Ele aparece o diretório.

Comment: Mas apenas o diretório da imagem. Eu previso do arquivo onde eu possa linkar o slider